# How to retrieve a specific html table from a web page in R?

Tags: r, web-scraping, html-table, rvest

A Merry Xmas to the `stackoverflow` team and readers!
I am using `Rstudio` and I am having a hard time trying to retrieve an `html` `table` from a web page. The web page is located [here](https://www.soccerpunter.com/soccer-statistics/England/Premier-League-2017-2018/head_to_head_statistics/all/675_Tottenham_Hotspur_FC/670_Southampton_FC) and the table I want to retrieve has the following XPath: //*[@id="h2hMatches"]

Here is what I've tried in terms of my `R` codes:

```
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)

webpage <- read_html("https://www.soccerpunter.com/soccer-statistics/England/Premier-League-2017-2018/head_to_head_statistics/all/675_Tottenham_Hotspur_FC/670_Southampton_FC")

tbls <- html_nodes(webpage, "table")

head(tbls)
```

The output of the above is the following:

```
{xml_nodeset (6)}
[1] <table border="0" align="center" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="1" class="normaltext">\n<tr>\n<td colspan="2" class= ...
[2] <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="content">\n<!--DWLayoutTable--><tr>\n<td valign="top" id="ce ...
[3] <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr>\n<td><table width="640" cellpadding="0" cellsp ...
[4] <table width="640" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">\n<tr>\n<td> \r\n\r\n                         ...
[5] <table id="h2hHead" width="100%">\n<tr>\n<td width="200"><h2><a href="/soccer-statistics/England/Premier-League-20 ...
[6] <table id="matchInfo" class="infoTable">\n<tr>\n<td class="infoName">Competition:</td>\n                        <t ...
```

I cannot find that a table Id which is equal to "h2Matches" from the output.

What am I doing wrong? Is there another approach to retrieving that specific table?

Comment: I think the table you're looking for is created by JavaScript after the page is loaded, meaning it's not part of the html you're reading. If that's the case, you'd need something like an `ajax` call to retrieve the data you need, and my guess is they won't allow that except on loading of their page (cross origin ajax requests are disabled by default).

Comment: Ok. So I'm out of luck here!

Comment: No, it's totally doable to d/l AJAX/XHR data. HOWEVER — via their [`robots.txt`](https://www.soccerpunter.com/robots.txt) : `# Contact us first if you have a legitimate reason to download data from this website.`. Their terms of use also indicate contact first before scraping. You rly don't want your  to be  cease-and-desist letter.

Comment: @hrbrmstr I understand their terms of use and it is not my intention to scrape their web pages without their permission. Thank you for bringing this to my attention. However, I am still interested to learn about how to do it! :-)

Comment: Then pick a different site or look at the countless #'s of R & 
AJAX/XHR request questions on SO. Smile-emoticons are no recompense for scofflaws.